# Video - take snapshot

Tags: javascript, html

I'm capturing webcam data to a HTML5 video.

I now wish to take a snapshop and set the src of an image to the snapshot.

I've looked around and can only find examples that output to canvas - but I need it going to an img.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: I just want to set an <img> tag on my page to the src of the snapshot. Like a preview.

Comment: Where is the snapshot located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one step further. You can use [**`toDataURL()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method to get the base64 data from the canvas, and then build a image with the data. Particularly, you can specify MIME type with the method as well, either JPG, PNG or else.

Comment: So perhaps save to a hidden canvas and then use toDataURL?

Comment: @panthro Yep, I once made a little mascot editor that used it. However, instead of showing in the page, I made it downloadable. http://myst729.github.io/Favatar/favatar2.html

Comment: @panthro I added a link to the method doc. You can take a look, there's an example that shows how it would work.